# forEach() and Apply() methods for two dimensional array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

I have an array whose elements are also arrays, each containing three elements. I want to call the `function calcMe(a,b,c){...}` for each of the elements of my main array using `forEach()` method, but I got really confused and don't know how to get it to work.

```
arr = [[1,5,4], [8,5,4], [3,4,5], [1,2,3]]
function calcMe(a,b,c){...}
arr.forEach(calcMe.Apply(-----, -----));
```

How do I pass each of the inner array's elements as arguments to my function using `Apply()`?

Comment: please add some example, how this should work.

Comment: And you can't pass through the array and address `a`, `b` and `c` as `function calcMe(arr) { a = arr[0], b = arr[1]` etc?

Comment: the function calcMe(a,b,c) should take 1,5,4 then 8,5,4 and so on as arguments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, `calcMe` doesn't seem to return a function, so you can't pass its return value to `forEach`.

I'm guessing you want something like

```js
var arr = [
  [1, 5, 4],
  [8, 5, 4],
  [3, 4, 5],
  [1, 2, 3]
]

function calcMe(a, b, c) {
  var pre = document.getElementById('pre')
  pre.innerHTML += 'calcMe arguments: ' +  a +","+ b +","+ c  + "<br/>";
}

arr.forEach(function(el, index) {
  // Could also use `arr[index]` instead of el
  calcMe.apply(this, el);
});
```

```html
<pre id='pre'></pre>
```

For a fancier version, [you can bind `Function.prototype.apply`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34747724/227299) to emulate creating a function like I did above.

Comment: But `arr[index]` is exactly `el`.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you used the index whether than the el (element reference) in the forEach callback?

Comment: @Mic no particular reason, clarifying the answer

Comment: thanks, that works great. I am just starting to learn javascript and don't really understand the function inside forEach, how exactly does it take the index of the main array

Comment: @jacqui_g [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) calls the function passed to it with three parameters: the first is the current element in the array, the second is the index, and the third is the array being iterated.

Answer (score 5):

`apply` calls a function immediately, so you can't use it directly because `forEach` expects a function reference. However, you can use `bind` on `apply` to achieve what you want:

```
arr.forEach(Function.apply.bind(calcMe, void 0));
```

The second argument will be the `this` value. You can provide whatever value instead of `void 0`.

```js
var arr = [[1,5,4],[8,5,4],[3,4,5],[1,2,3]];
function calcMe(a,b,c){
  document.querySelector('pre').textContent += [a,b,c] + '\n';
}
arr.forEach(Function.apply.bind(calcMe, void 0));
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```

Comment: I had never heard of `Function.apply` and `Function.call`, only the [prototype versions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function)

Comment: @JuanMendes Since `Function` is a function, it inherits from `Function.prototype`. So `Function.apply` is a shortcut of `Function.prototype.apply`.

Comment: So to clarify, `Function.apply.bind(calcMe, void 0)` is the same as doing `function() {calcMe.apply(null, arguments)}` or `calcMe.apply.bind(calcMe)`?

Comment: `Function.apply.bind(calcMe, void 0)` is the same as `calcMe.apply.bind(calcMe, void 0)` because `Function.apply === calcMe.apply`. And it's almost the same as `function(subArr) {calcMe.apply(void 0, subArr)}`, the difference is that the formers pass additional arguments to `apply`, which are ignored.

Comment: @jacqui_g Basically you can choose if you want to `bind` `apply` or wrap it in a function expression. What you can't do is call `apply` directly.

Comment: @jacqui_g I am not sure if I would use this idiom, because it can be hard to grasp and may trip up developers. However, you should definitely play with it and understand it. If you know what is going on here, you're ahead of the JavaScript curve

Answer (score 2):

You need to provide a function for [`.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach). The function will be run over each element of your main array.

Depending on what `calcMe` does, you might need to provide the right context for it in `calcMe.apply`. The first agrument of [`.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) is the context (`this` keyword in the function). I just put `null`, but you can pass what works for you.

```
var arr = [[1,5,4], [8,5,4], [3,4,5], [1,2,3]];
function calcMe(a,b,c){
    console.log(a, b, c);
}
arr.forEach(function (params) {
    calcMe.apply(null, params);
})
```

If you are willing to use ES6, you can use [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) and [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator):

```
arr.forEach(params => calcMe(...params));
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're interested in [ECMAScript 6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#6th_Edition_-_ECMAScript_2015), here is the fastest and most elegant solution.

```js
'use strict';
let arr = [
  [1, 5, 4],
  [8, 5, 4],
  [3, 4, 5],
  [1, 2, 3]
];

function calcMe(a, b, c) {
  document.querySelector('p').innerHTML += `${a},${b},${c}<br>`;
}

for (let item of arr) {
  calcMe(...item);
}

// Or
arr.forEach(item => calcMe(...item));
```

```html
<p></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can provide a lambda function

```
arr.forEach((u)=>{console.log(calcMe.apply(null, u))});
```

If you don't need to access object context, bind `null` to the first argument should be fine. Otherwise, bind the object you desire.