# Returning array of largest numbers

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

I have this little script that will return the largest number of an array, it works, except it doesn't work for multidimensional arrays.

How can I tweak this to return an array of the largest numbers within a multidimensional array?

Source:

```
function largestOfFour(arr) {
    for(var x=0;x < arr.length; x++){
        var largest = Math.max.apply(Math, arr[x]);
        return largest;
    }
}
```

Example:

```
> function largestOfFour(arr) {
...     for(var x=0;x < arr.length; x++){
.....         var largest = Math.max.apply(Math, arr[x]);
.....         return largest;
.....     }
... }
undefined
> largestOfFour([[4, 5, 1, 3], [13, 27, 18, 26], [32, 35, 37, 39], [1000, 1001, 857, 1]]);
5
>
```

Expected output:

```
[5, 27, 39, 1001]
```

Comment: are you willing to use a module like underscore?

Comment: do you know the dimensions (depth) in advance?

Comment: the for loop can be replaced with `var largest = Math.max.apply(Math, arr);`.

Comment: @lipp I am not, but I am willing to learn? And yes the depth stays that same as the example

Comment: @NinaScholz I don't need the loop?

Comment: @Tushar Woah, you're right that's literally the same question

Comment: [`arr.map(Math.max.apply.bind(Math.max, null))`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32679435/2025923) **That's it**

Comment: please have a look to another reference of apply.bind http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34747551/foreach-and-apply-methods-for-two-dimensional-array-javascript/34747724#34747724

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just map the result of the single results.

```js
function largestOfFour(array) {
    return array.map(function (a) {
        return Math.max.apply(null, a);
    });
}

var largest = largestOfFour([[4, 5, 1, 3], [13, 27, 18, 26], [32, 35, 37, 39], [1000, 1001, 857, 1]]);
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(largest, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

The above mentioned (@Tushar) short version

```js
function largestOfFour(array) {
    return array.map(Math.max.apply.bind(Math.max, null));
}

var largest = largestOfFour([[4, 5, 1, 3], [13, 27, 18, 26], [32, 35, 37, 39], [1000, 1001, 857, 1]]);
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(largest, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: [Can be shortened](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36940109/returning-array-of-largest-numbers#comment61439382_36940109)

Comment: This makes perfect sense, thank you.

Comment: @Tushar ever shorter `arr.map(e => Math.max(...e))`

Comment: @isvforall ES6, yaay! Updated my answer. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use ES6 [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) and [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator).

```
arr.map(e => Math.max(...e))
```

`map` will iterate(i.e. nested arrays) over all the elements of main array and `Math.max(...e)` will return the max element of that array. The `...e` will pass the elements of `e` array individually to the `max()`.

```js
var arr = [ [4, 5, 1, 3], [13, 27, 18, 26], [32, 35, 37, 39], [1000, 1001, 857, 1] ]

var res = arr.map(e => Math.max(...e))

document.write(res);
```

Comment: I really like that. :)